# Can we publish Bots on FB Messenger, Skype, etc without registering on Botframework

Tags: botframework, chatbot

Can we publish a Bot (built with Microsoft Builder SDK) on Facebook Messenger without registering on Bot Framework?
and the Bot would not be hosted on Azure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the Bot in order to enable it to work with the supported channels (like Facebook). This doesn't mean that the Bot will be publicly available. You can register the bot but keep it unpublished.

If you want to use the Bot in a custom channel, you might have to consider using the [DirectLine API](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline/#navtitle). [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1215) is a related thread.

You can host the Bot on other cloud providers. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1321) is a thread discussing about hosting the Bot in AWS.